# Maximum requests for google maps api?

Tags: google-maps

How many requests are you allowed to make using google maps API?

Comment: For testing purposes you can [bypass those limits](https://github.com/Pithikos/Geoexplorer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the usage policy [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits). For free version of the Geocoding API, the max allowable limit if 2500 requests per day.